# How can I remove email address from my excel columns using formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How can I remove the email address and the phone number from the D columns using formula ?

I tried `=LEFT(D2,FIND("@",D2))` but it doesn't fully remove the email address.

I tried to match the columns to left to remove but that didn't work.

```
=LEFT(D2,LEN(B2))

=TRIM(MID(D2,LEN(B2)+2,1000))
```

[image]

Comment: I hope that's dummy data and not real PII

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your data consists of a set of items that:

- are separated by **comma space**
- **may** have an email as the last item

If this is always the case, then consider the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function noemail(s As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, L As Long

    If InStr(s, "@") = 0 Then
        noemail = s
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    L = Len(s)
    For i = L To 1 Step -1
        If Mid(s, i, 1) = "," Then
            noemail = Left(s, i - 1)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    
End Function
```

It checks the string for **@**.  If the **@** is present, it looks for the preceding **comma** and clips the string at the point:

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the UDF from Excel:

```
=noemail(A1)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the following formula:

```
=LEFT(D2,(FIND((MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}&", ",D2)),0)-1)&",",D2)))
```

**Explanation**

- `FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}&", ",D2)`: finds if there is a number followed by a comma. This returns 10 values. Only 1 will be correct.
- `MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}&", ",D2)),0)`: combines the previous formula with `ISNUMBER` and `MATCH` functions to obtain the index of the number in the array constant.
- `FIND((MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}&", ",D2)),0)-1)&",",D2)`: uses the index from the array constant to return the position of the string.
- `LEFT(D2,(FIND((MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}&", ",D2)),0)-1)&",",D2)))`: combines all the above to return everything except the email address

[image]

Note that if the second part of the string ends with a number followed by a comma, then this formula will not work.

Comment: I think OP want to do the opposite to this, remove the email and just have the remaining text

Comment: @PeterH You are 100% right. Will delete my answer.

Comment: Great answer +1 from me !

Answer (score 2):

This will return all parts that do not contain `@`

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[not(contains(.,'@'))]"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As much as I like the UDF from Gary's Student, you may also achieve this with a formula:

```
=LEFT(D2,SEARCH(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(D2), " ", REPT(" ", 99)), 99)),D2,1))
```

**Note.** I copied part of this from another answer that has been removed.
(will delete mine if it gets reposted)

Comment: If a column doesn't have an email address it removes the required data

Comment: Don't delete your answer. I have (re)posted a formula that is different from what I posted before.